# Elegant way of getting a uint32_t from four elements of a uint8_t array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a `uint8_t` array from which I need to take the first 4 elements, 32 bits, to create a `size_t` (`uint32_t` on my machine).

Example non-working code:

```
uint8_t array[8];
array[0] = 128;
array[1] = 128;
array[2] = 0;
array[3] = 0;
size_t size = array[0]; //results in 128
size = *array; //also results in 128
```

The bytes of the first four indices of that array are `80 80 00 00`.

I want that `size_t` to result in 128 + 256*128 by reading the first 4 bytes of data from that array, little endian. Is there a way to make that `size_t` initialization read those 4 bytes directly as if the array were any old chunk of memory rather than having to manually add and multiply to find the value I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it in a portable way (i.e. endian independent) use the shift operators. Something like

```
uint32_t result = 0;
for(int i=3; i>=0; --i) {
    result <<= 8;
    result += array[i];
}
// result now holds the value you desire
```

Comment: I didn't know anything about those shift operators; this works better than what I said. This results in the machine doing math, but it seems like it would only amount to copying bits. Would this be any slower than doing what I suggested but with some compiler flags to detect endianness?

Comment: Don't worry about the speed until (1) you have proven that your code is too slow and (2) you have proven that even with all the optimization turned on. Most compilers do a good job optimizing this kind of thing. Just loop unrolling will go along way toward fixing this and modern x86 machines have all kinds of fancy opcodes just for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I got two basically equivalent answers that are both great, but this one is a little cleaner and more expandable, so I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: As a caution: if the bits came from a source that wrote it as a `uint32_t`, their order may differ based on the source endianness.  In short, make sure when writing it out you follow something like the above as well (but backwards), or restrict writing to only one endianness architecture.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal way:

```
inline uint32 little_endian_to_uint32(uint8 *p)
{
    return p[0] + p[1] * 0x100ul + p[2] * 0x10000ul + p[3] * 0x1000000ul;
}
```

Your compiler ought to generate the optimum assmebly code.

Answer (score -1):

Got it. Right after I asked, of course!

```
uint32_t size = *((uint32_t*) array);
```

Comment: Apart form the aliasing issues, I'll warn you that will *not* work if the same byte sequence is used on a big-vs-little endian system.

Comment: @WhozCraig In what context? If a big-endian machine writes to that using, for example, `*((uint32_t*) array) = 8`, it'll also read `*((uint32_t*) array)` as 8.

Comment: @9000 The code you wrote in your question is not independent of endianess. Yes, punning casts one way and then the other way are fine on any machine, but if you plan to do anything with the intermediate representation you need to know how your machine handles integer representations.

Comment: You only showed *read*-ing data; not reading+writing on the same machine. Send that byte sequence from a IBM AIX to a Linux x64 box (however you want to do it, socket, file, doesn't matter) and things will go to hell quickly. Of course type-punning will work on local-mach.

Comment: @dmckee My bad, I was thinking about my specific use case rather than any generic "here are bytes in an array, read them" case.

Comment: I upvoted this because big-endian computers seem to be really rare, and this is elegant.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I think most servers use big endian, as do Macs made before 2006 (PowerPC). Don't up vote my answer ;)